# Why am I not able to revive the colour of my div element?

Tags: javascript, html, css, onmouseover, onmouseout

I want the previous colour back when the mouse is out. But it seems like style attribute is not accepting the hexadecimal colour value, in-fact not even the normal hardcoded ones?
How can I overcome this problem.

```
function update(element){
document.getElementById('zone').style.backgroundImage= "url(" +element.src+ ")";
document.getElementById('zone').innerHTML= element.alt;
}

function undo(){
document.getElementById('zone').style.backgroundColor= "grey";
document.getElementById('zone').innerHTML= "Hover Over";
}
```

The update function is executed during a onmouseover() and undo is executed during onmouseout().

Comment: It looks like you're not setting the backgroundImage to none when you mouse out.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested above, you need to unset your background image with 
`document.getElementById('zone').style.backgroundImage= "unset";`.
in your function it would look like this

```
function undo(){
document.getElementById('zone').style.backgroundImage= "unset";
document.getElementById('zone').style.backgroundColor= "grey";
document.getElementById('zone').innerHTML= "Hover Over";
}
```

Also, i would suggest on using `onmouseenter`  instead of `onmouseover` since the latter may fire multiple times when hovering an element if you're not careful with your html structure, wich can cause performance issues in bigger functions.

Comment: Thank you so much. I did as you recommended. It works fine now. Thank you.